# c18 assembly inside function problem. unidentified label (bit names)

Tags: pic, c, assembly

Here is the data_write function I'm looking at.  I've been told that this method (from the textbook) is not good and I should be using the C method (that is currently commented out).  When the Cbits method is used, any arguments after the _asm/_endasm the compiler doesn't recognize the bit names (they don't turn green).

If I use only the assembly method, I get a string of errors [1111] about the undefined label (WR, GIE, EECON1, etc.) inside this function.  Do I have to somehow re-define the ADC.h inside the function?  Basically, all of the register names (EECON1, etc) and bit names (WR, WREN, etc.) are not recognized inside the function "data_write" if they are inside the assembly tags (_asm/_endasm).  If I use the Cbits.BIT method, I get a generic syntax error and the bits following _endasm are not identified (turn green).

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <p18f452.h>
#include <delays.h>
#include <adc.h>

int result;                         // used in ADC result handling
int write_point=0x64;               // used in data_write function. initial=d100

void data_write (int write_point, int result);   // declare prototype

void main(void)  // <==should this be 'int main (void)' b/c i'm passing result to another function ?
{
    while (1) {
    // sensor 1 configured to port AN0
        OpenADC(ADC_FOSC_8 & ADC_RIGHT_JUST & ADC_5ANA_0REF, ADC_CH0 & ADC_INT_OFF);
                            //configures ADC for port AN0 = sensor 1 input
            ConvertADC();               // initiate conversion of sensor1 @ AN0
            while(BusyADC());           // waiting to complete conversion
            result=ReadADC();           // read the result of sensor1 @ AN0
            data_write(result, write_point);
        CloseADC();
                    }
        }

void data_write (int write_point, int result) {

/*        EECON1bits.EEPGD = 0       // points to data memory
         EECON1bits.CFGS = 0        // access data eeprom
         EECON1bits.WREN = 1        // enable write to data eeprom
         INTCONbits.GIE=0           // disable interrupt
** if I substitute this method of bit control, this 2nd portion belongs after 
 * the asm arguments, but the bits (WR, GIE, WREN) will not be identified
 * either an I get a syntax error. (of course commenting out the bcf/bsf statements)
        EECON1bits.WR = 1       // enable bit to start the write operation
        INTCONbits.GIE = 1      // re-enable interrupt
        EECON1bits.WREN = 0    // restores the write command to =disabled */

_asm
 movlw  write_point        // starting data memory address = data_adr
 movwf  EEADR,A
 movlw  result              // gets data stored in "result" variable
 movwf  EEDATA,A            // places data into data memory holder
 bcf    EECON1,EEPGD,A      // points to data memory
 bcf    EECON1,CFGS,A       // access data eeprom
 bsf    EECON1,WREN,A       // enable write to data EEPROM
 bcf    INTCON,GIE,A         // disable interrupt
 movlw  0x55                // start flash erase sequence
 movwf  EECON2,A
 movlw  0xAA
 movwf  EECON2,A            // end flash erase sequence
 bsf    EECONN1,WR,A        // enable bit to start the write operation
 bsf    INTCON,GIE,A        // re-enable interrupt
 bcf    EECON1,WREN         // restores the write command to =disabled
 _endasm



 write_point = write_point+2;  // increment address by 2
 if (write_point >= 0xC6)      // if address >= d'198
     write_point = 0x64;       // resets starting point to d'100

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the commented out C part, you don't appear to have have any ending semicolons (e.g. first line should be `EECON1bits.EEPGD = 0;`) , so the compiler certainly won't like that.

For the inline assembly, IIRC the register names hould b e usable, but I think you have to specify operands fully (e.g. instead of `movwf  EECON2,A` you do `movwf  EECON2,0`)
It's possible the bit names must be specified by number instead of name too, for example instead of `bcf    EECON1,EEPGD,A` you do `bcf    EECON1, 7, 0` (EEPGD is bit 7 of EECON1) The `A` at the end is not right anyway, this should be 1 or 0 (or W or F in MPASM)
It's been a while since I used the inline assembly for anything like this so memory is fuzzy, but try it and let us know how it goes.

Comment: Yay!  dropping those ",A" to ",0" did the trick!  Thanks @Oli !!!